# Why my inception and LSTM model with 2M parameters take 1G GPU memory?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

The model mainly builds on inception and LSTM, and it is implemented by Keras on tensorflow 2.x. The saved model parameters take only 2M space. The model is trained on-the-fly with batch size of 32 and data volume for each batch of 0.25M. The worker in model.fit_generator is 20 with use_multiprocessing=True.

However, I have observed it takes 1G of GPU memory. I cannot figure out the reason, and I also do not know which tools can be used to monitor the GPU memory cost for different parts of the model during the training.

Below show the details of the model:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The allocated GPU memory is not only for parameters but also for activations  and gradients for the backward pass.

In addition you have to consider that the following things affect the amount of memory used:

- Batch size: more images in the batch means more activations
- Number of workers: every worker need some amount of memory to operate